# Какие типы объектных файлов на Linux бывают?

Tags: linux, c

Имеется ввиду файлы, которые обычно имеют суффикс .o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *Перемещаемый* файл содержит код и данные, подходящие для линковки с другими перемещаемыми файлами, дающей исполняемый или разделяемый объектный файл.
2. *Исполняемый* файл содержит программу, пригодную для исполнения.
3. *Разделяемый* файл содержит код и данные, подходящие для линковки в двух случаях: для создания другого объектного файла и для создания образа процесса.